# Is there any way to get data from controller to filter?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs.

I want to use the data in filter which i have in my controller.

Is there any specific way to do dat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to pass the data as an additional parameter: `<span>{{ value | filter:anotherValue }}</span>`. This way, the `value` and `anotherValue` are controller's scope variables. The `filter` is your custom filter. The filter will receive the `anotherValue`content as the second parameter, and a change to it will reapply the filter. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/KbQAD/).

Another solution, if you it's not proper to pass the information along all times you write the filter, is to use a shared service between them. You can then expose the properties from the controller and use in the filter. Another [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/SFbgm) (just change the input text value).

Basically, this is what happens on the fiddle:

```js
// sets the shared data
mod.controller('Ctlr', function(sharedService) {
  sharedService.data = 'something';
}

// uses the shared data
mod.filter('customFilter', function(sharedService) {
  return function(input) {
     return input + sharedService.data;
  };
});

// the shared service that holds the data
mod.service('sharedService', function(){ 
  this.data = 'default value';
});
```

Comment: using service to share data is a good idea. Thanks a lot. it really helped me :-)

Comment: i want to watch my $scope variable which makes asynchronous call to a file. how to do that???

Comment: Didn't understood. What exactly you'd like to watch?

Comment: actually i have a scope variable which will request for json data from the server($scope.data=Data.query();) i want to watch this $scope.data is this possible?

Comment: You can watch pretty much anything using [scope.$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch). You should run through the [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/), [dev guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/), [API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/) and [docs](http://docs.angularjs.com). There is plenty to learn around there.

Answer (score 3):

in controller

```
$scope.variable=['1','2','3'];
```

in view

```
<span>{{ variable | f1 }}
```

in filter

```
angular.module('Filters', ['Services']).filter('f1', function() {
 var events=Events.query();
 return function(input) { 
 alert(input)->['1','2','3']
}; });
```